# grabbing windows forms, pop-ups and menus

Tags: c#, winapi, printing

I'm developing an application the screen grab a thrid party app.
Right now I've no problem in finding all the belonging forms, menus and popups in the 3rd party app I plan to grab, but i don't know how can I findout if the window I'm grabbing is a popup or a menu or whatever. 
Is there any function that given the window handle tells me what of window it is ?

Tks,
Jose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get much of this information from the Windows class.

Once you have the window handle (HWND), you can use [GetClassName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633582(VS.85).aspx) to get the window class name, then [GetClassInfo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633578(VS.85).aspx) to get info about the window class itself.

The window class info has the style, which contains much of this info about the class (ie: menus should be style #32768).  For details about Window Classes, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633574(VS.85).aspx).